# Sequence having property P

Tags: sequences-and-series

We say that a sequence $\{a_{n}\}$ has property $P$ if there exist a positive integer $m$ such that $a_n\le 1$ for every $n\ge m$. I need to find whether the sequence

$$a_n= \begin{cases}0.9 + \frac{200}{n} &\text{if }n\text{ is even}\\
 \frac{1}{n} &\text{if }n\text{ is odd}\end{cases}$$

has property $P$. Also I cannot use any result on limits.

I have not understood the question. Am I supposed to find some bound on the sequences mentioned? Please help. I shall be highly obliged. Sone hints will definitely help me. Please dont solve the question

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/93168/discussion-on-question-by-the-learner-sequence-having-property-p).

Answer (score 0):

To clear this question from the unanswered queue before closing this question, I'm transferring @DanielleTampieri's answer in the linked chat room here, so I'm making this CW.

You can use the fact that the subsequences for odd $n$ and even $n$ of $a_n$ are strictly decreasing since

\begin{split}
0.9+\frac{200}{n}&> 0.9+\frac{200}{n+1}\quad n\text{ even} \\
\frac{1}{n}&>\frac{1}{n+1}\quad n\text{ odd}
\end{split}

for all $n\in \Bbb N$.